# How can I test a method that initaiates a download as stream using Arquillian?

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I need to write a bunch of integration tests (Arquillian framework) and right now I'm struggling in a few areas. Here is an example of a method in a Controller, that initiates the creation of a Jasper Report, which is subsequently streamed to the client:

```
public void executeFibuAuswertung(){
    Report report = reportService.find(99913L);
    reportParameterForm.setReport(report);
    List<ReportParameter> reportParameters = Collections.emptyList();
    createExcelReport(reportParameters);
    reportExecutionController.streamReportResult();
}

public void streamReportResult(){
    EnumReportFormat format = reportParameterForm.getSelectedFormat();

    ServletUtils.streamToClient(reportParameterForm.getReportResult()
                , reportParameterForm.getReport().getTitle() + format.getFileExtention()
                , format.getContentType()
                , false);
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

How can I write a test for this using the Arquillian framework?

At this time, my test Looks like this:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    FacesContext context = ContextMocker.mockFacesContext();
    ContextMocker.mockPostback(context, false);
    ContextMocker.mockFacesMessages(context);
    ContextMocker.mockFindComponent(UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context), context);
}

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
@WindowScopeRequired
public void testExecuteAuswertung1() throws Exception {
    fibuController.executeAuswertung();
    byte[] content = reportParameterForm.getReportResult();
    Assert.assertNotNull(content);
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't make much sense. It is the following line of code that throws the NullPointerException:

```
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I implemented in the end:

```
@Mock
private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;

@Mock
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@Mock
ExternalContext externalContext;

@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    FacesContext context = ContextMocker.mockFacesContext();
    when(context.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(externalContext);
    ContextMocker.mockPostback(context, false);
    ContextMocker.mockFacesMessages(context);
    ContextMocker.mockNavigationhandlers(context);
    ContextMocker.mockFindComponent(UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context), context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a complete answer and it is opinionated

You have methods which have no input or output(only side effect) and they containing sequence of procedures. If it is possible test each step of sequence with test input and expected values.
 If for some calls it is not feasible for some reasons to test them directly for using real components then mock them out. If you can call some part of the methods of any component but other part is not feasible use spies.

And try to stay away from state-full designs and side effect only methods as much as you can.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks! I'll work on reducing those side effect only methods.

Comment: I would still appreciate if anyone can suggest the easiest way to test the second method, specifically, what Mocks will I have to create. I suppose the sending a stream method ``ServletUtils.streamToClient` method is fairly standard.